# Getting custom code out of CGI.pm

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu-10.04

We have a custom site written in Perl that uses a slightly modified version of CGI.pm. During server updates, CGI.pm may be overwritten when it is updated. My goal is to be able to update the server without affecting the site - i.e. change the code that relies on the modified CGI.pm. Unfortunately I am not very familiar with Perl syntax or best practice.

Here is a diff of the modified CGI.pmn (line numbers are off from the most recent version of CGI.pm):

```
--- CGI.pm.orig Tue Nov  7 12:14:09 2006
+++ CGI.pm      Tue Nov  7 12:13:29 2006
@@ -3386,7 +3386,7 @@ sub read_multipart {
               if (defined $self->{'.upload_hook'})
                {
                   $totalbytes += length($data);
-                   &{$self->{'.upload_hook'}}($filename ,$data, $totalbytes, $self->{'.upload_data'});
+                   &{$self->{'.upload_hook'}}($filename ,$data, $totalbytes, $self->{'.upload_data'}, $param, $header{'Content-Type'});
               }
               print $filehandle $data if ($self->{'use_tempfile'});
           }
```

The code that relies on this diff follows:

```
my %file_hash = ();
my $page = new CGI(\&file_reader, \%file_hash, 0);

my $session = &get_session($page);


foreach my $param_name (keys %file_hash) {
        my $notes_param = $param_name . "_notes";
        &store_file($file_hash{$param_name}, $page->param($notes_param),
                    &get_session_name($session));
}
```

Without the diff, when the file is stored, the $param_name variable appears to be empty.

What is the best way to handle this? As I said before, my main goal is to simplify updates to the server; is there some way to either

a) (preferably) get %file_hash to work properly without a modified version of CGI.pm
b) prevent updates to CGI.pm (and is this a bad idea)

Comment: CGI.pm is a mess, and you're right, you're better off without a modified version. About your diff - is there some other part that references the `$param` variable? What does it contain? Better yet, I would scrap the modified CGI and look at the problem. What are you trying to do, why do you need the `$file_hash{param_name}` variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried submitting this to the CGI [RT](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=CGI) as a desired improvement? It seems reasonable to pass `$param` and `\%header` (rather than `$header{'Content-Type'}`) to the callback.

To answer your question, you could install CGI in a local directory. The directories in the `PERL5LIB` env var are searched first, so your CGI version would be found instead of the one installed by the Ubuntu.

Comment: This sounds helpful - how can I check the PERL5LIB env variable? I assume that's a perl environmental variable, because 'env' doesn't display that variable. Also, where do I find the CGI RT queue? Sorry for the basic Questions, but I have very little experience with Perl.

Comment: @JohnB, Perl always checks for it, so you don't need to do anything except populate it. If you install CGI to `~/perl5/lib` (simply putting `CGI.pm` there would work in this case), then add `export PERL5LIB="$HOME/perl5/lib"` to your login script. `PERL5LIB` is documented in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Comment: @JohnB, ug, that's not really gonna help you when you the web server runs your scripts. Adding `use lib "/home/johnb/perl5/lib";` to your script would be an alternative to using `PERL5LIB`.

Comment: I was just trying to figure that out, thanks for the tip - it sounds like all I need to do is to move CGI.pm to our non accessible library path.

Comment: Just one quick question, and I'll set this question as answered - where can I find the CGI RT? I can't seem to locate it via google.

Comment: @JohnB, Click on "RT" in "CGI RT" in the original post :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the CGI.pm maintainer. I think there is a better option than using a local copy of CGI.pm. Instead, create a sub-class, and use the my subclass in your application. It would look like this:

```
package My::CGI;
use parent 'CGI';

sub my_sub_that_modified {
  ...
}

1;
```

So, you just need to copy in the subroutine that you modified. Then, when you upgrade CGI.pm, you likely don't need to touch your application, unless your modified subroutine changes.

With the "local lib" option, you would still need to manually merge in security updates and other changes you might want to into your local copy. The sub-class route minimizes that.

An example of this approach is [Bugzilla::CGI](http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/3.6/annotate/7142/Bugzilla/CGI.pm) which makes several changes in their sub-class.